# Trying to call a function in main and not get 2 outputs

Tags: python, function, math, syntax-error

I have a homework problem, which I will show below, that is asking me to package a square root function inside a main function. If the user hits the enter key it exits the loop, else it just continues running. I'm running into 2 problems here, the first is that whenever I run it I always get 2 outputs, which I know why that is but I can't seem to get around it. The 2nd is I don't know how to get the user to hit enter and quit the program without converting everything to strings.

```
import math

def newton():
     x = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))

     tolerance = 0.000001
     estimate = 1.0

     while True:
          estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
          difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
          if difference <= tolerance:
              break

     print("The program's estimate is", estimate)
     print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))

def main():
     x = str(input("Enter a positive number: "))
     if x == '':
          return
     else:
          x = float(x)
          newton()
main()
```

Here's an example of the error

```
Enter a positive number: 2
Enter a positive number: 2
The program's estimate is 1.4142135623746899
Python's estimate is      1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: you ask for the input twice. Once in the main and once in the newton.

Comment: What do you mean "I always get 2 outputs"? You have 2 prints commands, so it prints two lines.

Comment: I know, I am unsure how to get around that though..

Comment: Just start the `main()` with `newton()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def newton(x):
    tolerance = 0.000001
    estimate = 1.0

    while True:
        estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
        difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
        if difference <= tolerance:
            break

    print("The program's estimate is", estimate)
    print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))

 def main():
     x = str(input("Enter a positive number: "))
     if x == '':
         return
     else:
         x = float(x)
         newton(x)
```

Try running this. You have to pass `x` into `newton(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You need only ask for the input once and pass the result to the newton function. In order to keep looping i have added a loop in main that will keep asking for input. If the input can be converted to a float it will call newton if not then it will stop.

```
import math

def newton(number):
     tolerance = 0.000001
     estimate = 1.0

     while True:
          estimate = (estimate + number / estimate) / 2
          difference = abs(number - estimate ** 2)
          if difference <= tolerance:
              break

     print("The program's estimate is", estimate)
     print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(number))

def main():
    while True:
        x = str(input("Enter a positive number: "))
        try:
            x = float(x)
            newton(x)
        except ValueError as ve:
            break
main()
```